# a matrix making using i, j for-loop (for 2*9 shape)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I hope to make the a matrix using i, j for-loop.
The code I tried is as below. The output 'xcount1' shows 1 by 18 shape.
but, the output I hope is 2 by 9 shape as below.

```
xcount1 = [[0. 0.],[0. 1.],[0. 2.],[1. 0.],[1. 1.],[1. 2.],[2. 0.],[2. 1.],[2. 2.]]
```

How the below code need to modified for above output?

```
import numpy as np
xcount1 = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        xcount1 = np.append(xcount1,[i,j])
print(np.shape(xcount1))
```

Comment: I made the mistake to leave the question.  The output 'xcount1' shows 1 by 18 shape. but, the output I hope is 2 by 9 shape.

Comment: `np.mgrid[:3.,:3.].reshape(2,-1).T`, IIUC. `np.indices((3,3)).reshape(2,-1).T` is faster for integers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need numpy here. Simple pythonic way of doing it would be

```
xcount1 = [[i,j]for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
```

With lists similarly

```
xcount1 = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        xcount1.append([i,j])
print(xcount1)
```

##### Numpy Way

```
import numpy as np
xcount1 = np.empty((0,2))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        xcount1 = np.append(xcount1, np.array([[i,j]]), axis=0)
```

##### A different numpy approach

```
np.flip(np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(3))).reshape(-1, 2), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  It works really well. If possible, please let me know what the problem in my code? append (vstack) funtion does not works.

Comment: @kuksundang For your doubt about why `np.append()` doesn't work. Check the docs for [`np,append()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html). You'll find that you need to provide an axis to prevent the list from getting flattened.

Comment: Better to check like that the doc. But also I believe if you check the way I have mentioned now, would clear your idea a lot regarding the axis and how to handle this thing @kuksundang Check the answer now

Answer (score 2):

A fast way to do this in `numpy` (without doing all the work to generate a `list` of `list`s in Python, just to convert it to `numpy` at the end and get no vectorization benefits during construction) is:

```
# Make a range of floats from 0 to 8, double each one in place, then reshape it
# so it becomes nine two-element subarrays that look like:
array([[0., 0.], [1., 1.], [2., 2.], ... [7., 7.], [8., 8.]])
xcount1 = np.arange(9, dtype=float).repeat(2).reshape(9,2)

xcount1[:, 0] //= 3  # Divide first element of each two element subarray by 3
xcount1[:, 1] %= 3   # Reduce secodnd element of each subarray modulo 3

# xcount is now *exactly* what you expected
print(xcount)
```

which outputs:

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 2.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 1.]
 [1. 2.]
 [2. 0.]
 [2. 1.]
 [2. 2.]]
```

Your original code didn't work because `numpy.append`, when not provided an `axis` argument, flattens both input and output before appending, so you lose your structure. I'm not sufficiently expert with `numpy` to make it build the correct way from scratch using `append` (that said, `np.append` is incredibly slow, making a copy every time, so it's a bad solution anyway), but it's easy to `reshape` it once you're done. Just add:

```
xcount1 = xcount1.reshape(9,2)
```

to the end of your code and it will reshape it to match the groupings you intended (though it would be much slower than my code, or even just `xcount1 = np.array([[i, j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)], dtype=float)` which doesn't benefit from any vectorization, but for small enough inputs it doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 1):

If you read the docs for [`np.append()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) you'll find out that we need to provide an axis to prevent the list from getting flattened. Earlier when you did not provide an axis the list was getting flattened which means it was getting converted to `1-D` just like in your output. To prevent that you need to provide an axis of the row i.e. `axis = 0`(in order to append it to each row.).
Also, you need to make sure that your `xcount1` has the same dimensions as the `[i,j]` so use `np.empty((0,2))`.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np

xcount1 = np.empty((0,2)) # Create an empty list with desired dimension
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        xcount1 = np.append(xcount1,np.array([[i,j]]), axis = 0) # Provide axis of rows and convert the list to `np.array()`

print(xcount1)
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 2.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 1.],
       [1., 2.],
       [2., 0.],
       [2., 1.],
       [2., 2.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `np.indices` and some transposing/reshaping:

```
np.indices((3,3)).transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,2)
Out[]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Or, as @MichaelSczcesny noted in the commments, `np.indices((3,3)).reshape(2,-1).T` works as well.